# In JavaFX firing an event when the mouse is pressed and enters a node

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

In JavaFX, how can I fire an event when the mouse enters a node and the primary button is pressed? MOUSE_ENTERED doesn't work here as it doesn't fire an event when the mouse buttons are pressed. I am new in JavaFX and didn't find anything useful googling.

Comment: Read about the different kinds of "gestures" described in the Javadoc of [`MouseEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html). From your description it sounds like you want a "full press-drag-release" gesture.

Answer (score 0):

The `MOUSE_ENTERED` event is not triggered since a Click + Move counts as a drag. The MOUSE_DRAGGED event however is only triggered on the source of the drag. So the only way I can think of achieving this would be to listen to drag events on your scene, and filtering according to your criteria:

```java
Button button = new Button("MyButton");
StackPane sp = new StackPane(button);
scene = new Scene(sp, 600, 600);
scene.setOnMouseDragged(ev -> {
    if (ev.getButton() != MouseButton.PRIMARY) return;
    if (ev.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode() != button && !button.getChildrenUnmodifiable().contains(ev.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode())) return;
    System.out.println("Hovered over the button while mouse button is pressed!");
});
```

The `getPickResult().getIntersectedNode()` returns the node which your drag intersects with right now. However depending on where you drag, this would not be the button but the text on the button. That's why I included the children as well.

Overall seems a bit hacky, but should do the trick.

Comment: If the OP starts a "full press-drag-release" gesture then the mouse events can be sent to nodes other than the source. See [this documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) for more information.

Comment: That's correct, but it didn't sound like that was what he asked for.